# need to define a "modifiable" global variable in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, global-variables

I have the following issue. I have two classes that manipulate information but they are completely disconnected, i.e. I can't reach the other class.

I need both classes to use a certain value. For example, class A sets the value foo = A and class B needs to be able to read that value and rest foo to nil.

I thought about creating the variable in the main app delegate, but can't figure out how.

Ideas?!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global variables are generally bad idea. Based on your description i think you can use [KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) to inform class B about the changes in 'foo'.

But if you relly need a global variable you can do this:

```
@interface YourAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
}
@property (nonatomic) NSString *foo;
@end

@implementation YourAppDelegate
@synthesize foo;
...
@end


@implementation ClassA
...
- (void)someMethod {
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.foo = @"NewValueOfFoo";
}
...
@end


@implementation ClassB
...
- (void)otherMethod {
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"Value of foo: %@", appDelegate.foo);  //This will print: "Value of foo: NewValueOfFoo"
}
...
@end
```

Comment: GojaNDo I need to synthesize the foo in the app delegate .m?

Comment: GajaN, You didn't declare NSString *foo in the class data area, would it work?

Comment: @leo It's works since [Objective-C 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C_2.0). In previous versions the compiler complains

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "completely disconnected". Depending on what you're trying to do, you could use NSUserDefaults

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

or NSNotifications

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

If class A doesn't need to know about class B, you could consider delegation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't he just do this?

A. Add 2 new files to your project: `GlobalValues.h` and `GloblaValues.m`.

B. Open `GlobalValues.h`, and declare all your needed variables.

`extern NSString *MyServiceName; // name of the 'service':`

C. Open `GlobalValues.m`, and start the new file by importing `GlobalValues.h`, and assign values to the variables you declared in the header file:

`#import "GlobalValues.h"`

`NSString *MyServiceName = @"MyService is called THIS";`

D. In the implementation files of the classes that need to use these variables, you would put - at the very beginning:

`#import "GlobalValues.h"`